# How to update only that column which is modified in sql server table?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert data from XML string

```
<customer ID="1">
 <Value HNAME="Holand" Revenue="12,7865"/>
 <Value XNAME="Hemmer" Revenue="15,7865"/>
 82 more "Value" child with different set of revenue and <AlphabetCombinations>NAME values.....
<customer>
```

If XML came with same ID in customer tag

```
<customer ID="1">
 <Value HNAME="Holand" Revenue="12,7865"/>
 <Value XNAME="Hemmer" Revenue="17,7425"/>
 82 more "Value" child with different set of revenue and <AlphabetCombinations>NAME values.....
<customer>
```

Above XML value of Revenue is change for XNAME="Hemmer",I have to update value of only that column which is updated.there is 84 columns in my table,is there any query which update record for Customer ID =1 and update only modified column,I don't intended to update all the values again for customer.

```
Customer(ID,HNAME,XNAME,.....)
```

Comment: Do you think it is more efficient to update just the columns that have changed? [In my testing, it's usually not](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates). I imagine it's even less efficient when you're talking about parsing two sides of XML before even comparing...

Comment: thanks...Aaron Bertrand..